# Wifi not showing on Kali linux

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

Hi I am new to Kali linux untill today wifi works fine I could connect my home wifi without any issue but suddenly it is not working anymore available wifi hotspot not showing as shown below [image]

Could you please help me with this 
Thank You

Comment: Have a look here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399627/256455

Comment: This is not a security question but a Linux question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal and type: `iwconfig`

Do you see any wireless interfaces listed? Are they in 'Monitor' mode? It is possible that during a wireless penetration test, you put the wireless adapter in monitor mode using something like 'airmon-ng'. If so, bring it back using:

`airmon-ng stop wlan0mon`

(this is assuming that the monitor interface was called 'wlan0mon')

Also, check `network` in settings and see if a wireless interface is available there. If this is a VM, then you might not have access to the wireless interface because the host might be using it. If you are using a VM to host Kali, you need a USB wireless adapter (like an Alpha card) to be able to access wireless interace within Kali.